# Login, logout and duration time in php and mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, logout, duration

I would like to store the login, logout and duration time in database.

- The login time is created when the user is authenticated(successfully logged in)
- The logout time is created when the user clicks the logout button
- The duration is logout - login time. (logout minus login)

But the problem is, what if the user didnt click the logout button. Here are the situations:

- Internet loss
- Close the browser/tab. (I need this must use javascript, but i donnu how to do it, any idea?)

EDIT:

I forgot to add something to the question, the program is a full flash program, there is no navigation to other page. Only 1 page

Comment: You really only need to store the start & end datetimes - you can calculate the duration as needed, rather than store it.

Comment: How about the logout things. I forgot to add something to the question, the program is a full flash program, there is no navigation to other page. Only 1 page

Comment: The default session settings on webservers is 20 min.  If there's no logout, 20 after the login is about the most you can assume.  There's no reliable way to know when a connection gave out, and it's not worth an AJAX call to me to write a temp value every so often to track.

Comment: The other half of your question has been asked before - e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/887919/how-to-detect-if-the-user-is-logout-in-php

Comment: @Dominic: You mean checking via $_SESSION time activity? Whenever user click a thing, do a check? I afraid I cant implement into my system. It will cause lagginess. How about, js. window.onunload event? I am not sure whether its good to use it. Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't rely on receiving an event for the user logging out, if they simply close their browser, or disappear from the internet.

In this case you'll have to have a session timeout of some kind, and record the logout when your app realises their session is too old.

If this is a real requirement, then I'd say you need a "cron" job monitoring the sessions for timeout. When a session has timed out, if the were logged on, it then records a "logout" event for that user.

Note that you can't use (for example) ASPNET's Session_End event, because that won't be reliably called either (for example if the server process restarts).

Another option is to add the logout time next time that user logs on - when they log on, you check for old sessions and assume that any which weren't closed lasted for a fixed amount of time since the last page hit.

That's really all you can do.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to remember that all session/log-in functions in PHP are *usually* cookie based. So, changing the lifetime of the session cookie should solve your problem:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Also, you can set the PHP sessions so they only use cookies:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-only-cookies

Again, you can catch the browser window / tab close but ... why? For instance I may have your site open in multiple tabs. If I close one of those tabs should I automatically be logged out of your website? That's a very bad design. Instead, set the session lifetime so it expires if the *browser* is closed and not just a tab. (Note also that `window.unload` will logout when *any* window on your site that closes - including a pop-up or an iframe. Do you really want that?)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime

If you want to store session state in a database try any [one](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/saving-php-session-data-database-050711/page1.html) [of](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/PHP/Storing-PHP-Sessions-in-a-Database/) [these](http://www.raditha.com/php/session.php) [guides](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/session-handler.html). Or, roll your own with [session_set_save_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the closing of browser/tab, you can bind the `unload` event (`window.onunload`, jQuery's [`$(window).unload(fn)`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/unload#fn), or any other) to notify your server. A more general purpose solution would be to periodically ping your server (say, every 5 min), but it might be annoying to the user, so do so judiciously.