# Insert into Mysql table when user closes browser?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to insert a record into a Mysql table using php when the browser is closed, is this possible?

Comment: With only PHP : in short, no. You'd need JavaScript to do this. And it could be a bit risky for your database.

Comment: Semi-duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195581/remove-information-from-mysql-table-when-user-close-his-browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

javascript based but you can send an ajax request using the window.onclose event handler

jquery has the $(window).unload(....) which should handle the different implementations across browsers (some don't support the onclose event handler).