# PHP loading a function on startup

Tags: php

I am doing some PHP programming and have a question: How can I load a PHP function when the PHP script is first run, and only when it is first run?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Lock file

```
$lock = "run.lock" ;

if(!is_file($lock))
{
    runOneTimeFuntion(); //
    touch($lock);
}
```

**Edit 1**

One Time Function

```
runOneTimeFuntion ();
runOneTimeFuntion ();
runOneTimeFuntion ();
runOneTimeFuntion ();
runOneTimeFuntion ();
runOneTimeFuntion ();
runOneTimeFuntion ();
runOneTimeFuntion ();

function runOneTimeFuntion() {
    if (counter () < 1) {
        var_dump ( "test" );

    }

}

function counter() {
    static $count = 0;
    return $count ++;
}
```

Output

```
string 'test' (length=4)
```

Comment: Thank you Baba. That works well. However, if i close the browser and then load the same page, it doesnt detect it as a first page load. Do I have to maybe unlock the lock when the user has done with the page?

Comment: You can not really, see the many duplicates that cover that like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195581/remove-information-from-mysql-table-when-user-close-his-browser

Comment: never knew you want it to reload after you close the browser .. i would update my code in  min

Comment: I am not really sure how that code is meant to work... isn't there just a simple way to unlock the lock... the lock statment is otherwise working very well.

Comment: Use said you want a function to run once ...that mean it must not be called anywhere in php ...... by mistake or on purpose .. is that not what you want ???

Comment: No. I am wanting to call a PHP function once. Only when the page is first loaded. The situation is that this PHP page is loaded many times, I am just wnating the function to load the first time a user browses to the page.

Answer (score 1):

EACH time you start php script he starts as a new one, no matter how much times it was called befor.

And if you aware of re-declare functions, which is forbided in PHP, load functions from external fles useing:

```
<?php require_once(my_function_file.php); ?>
```

If you want scrpt remember if he was called befor, it's possible to do using some form of logging (data base\file) and cheacking it befor load... But I don't see any reason for this in case of function load...

Answer (score 0):

Or use a plain boolean...

```
$bFirstRun = true;

if( $bFirstRun ) {
    run_me();
    $bFirstRun = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a PHP function called `function_exists`

You can define your own function within this function, and then you could see whether this exists or not.

```
if (!function_exists('myfunction')) {
  function myfunction() {
    // do something in the function
  }
  // call my function or do anything else that you like, from here on the function exists and thus this code will only run once.
}
```

Read more about function_exists here: http://www.php.net/function_exists